# Using BigQuery connected sheet in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I wrote a simple script to send contents of a spreadsheet via email.
However, when I reference a sheet fetching data from BigQuery I get an exception.
It works for fine for any other sheet.

```
function send_daily_email() {

  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('BigQuery_Sheet');
  
  var lrow=sh.getLastRow();

  var email_body='<!DOCTYPE html>'
  email_body+='<html><body>'
  email_body+='<table>';
  for (var i=1; i<=lrow;i++)
    {
     email_body+='<tr>' ;
    for(var col=1; col<5; col++)
      {
      email_body+='<td>';
      email_body+=sh.getRange(i,col).getValue();
      email_body+='</td>';
      }//end of col for
      email_body+='</tr>';
    }//end of row for
    email_body+='</table></body></html>'
  MailApp.sendEmail({to:'someone@someone.com',subject:'testing daily email',htmlBody:email_body});
}
```

Error:

> Exception: The action is not supported for DATASOURCE sheet.

**Script works fine if I reference a standard sheet in Line#2 of the code.**

How do I get rid of this error please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to process data from a sheet that's linked with BigQuery, you'll run into limitations. Google Sheets doesn't allow direct interaction with BigQuery-connected sheets via App Script due to the nature of those sheets.

To navigate this issue, one solution is to copy the content of your BigQuery-connected sheet to a temporary regular sheet. From there, you can process the data as needed and subsequently remove the temporary sheet. I've provided an adjusted script below that should help you with this:

```
function dispatchEmail() {
  
  const workbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const datasourceSheet = workbook.getSheetByName('BigQuery_Sheet');
  const sheetValues = datasourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  const temporarySheet = workbook.insertSheet("EmailDataBuffer");
  temporarySheet.getRange(1, 1, sheetValues.length, sheetValues[0].length).setValues(sheetValues);
  
  const finalRow = temporarySheet.getLastRow();
  let constructedBody = '<!DOCTYPE html>'
  constructedBody += '<html><body>'
  constructedBody += '<table>';
  
  for (let rowIndex=1; rowIndex<=finalRow; rowIndex++) {
    constructedBody += '<tr>' ;
    for(let columnIndex=1; columnIndex<5; columnIndex++) {
      constructedBody += '<td>';
      constructedBody += temporarySheet.getRange(rowIndex, columnIndex).getValue();
      constructedBody += '</td>';
    }
    constructedBody += '</tr>';
  }
  
  constructedBody += '</table></body></html>'
  MailApp.sendEmail({to:'recipient@domain.com', subject:'Daily Report', htmlBody:constructedBody});
  
  workbook.deleteSheet(temporarySheet); // Remove the buffer sheet after sending the email
}
```

This should assist you in bypassing the aforementioned limitation. Remember, the idea is to temporarily place the data in a standard sheet, utilize it, and then remove the temporary sheet.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Same exception when executing this line
  const sheetValues = datasourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();